# Consistent estimator for $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[f(X_1,X_2)|X_1]^2]$

Tags: estimation, consistency

Suppose $(x_{i})_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. sample. I want to construct a consistent estimator of $\mu=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[f(X_1,X_2)|X_1]^2]$, where $f(x_1,x_2)\ne f(x_2,x_1)$. I use $X_1$ for random, $x_1$ for realization.

My attempt:  $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n[\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j=1,j\ne i}^n f(x_i,x_j)]^2$

reasoning: $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j=1,j\ne i}^n f(x_i,x_j)\xrightarrow{p}\mathbb{E}[f(x_i,X_j)|x_i]$ by the law of large number. Then, 
$\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}\mathbb{E}[f(x_i,X_j)|x_i]^2 $

I have run a simple simulation on matlab with $X$ is distributed as uniform (0,1) and $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1x_2^2$. My estimator seems working in this case.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to ask whether my attempt ($\hat{\mu}$) is a consistent estimator. If not, which part of my reasoning is wrong.